# What's the most efficient way to apply a function to all objects in a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Suppose I want to calculate the "popularity" field for all objects in my collection. It depends on the difference from the current time to the field "submitTime" and the numbers in the field "votes". This operation will run every hour. What's the most efficient way to run a function on all objects? Just an example, it could be any function:

```
function(){
    this.popularity = this.votes / (Date.now() - this.submitTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a function on all objects and save a popularity score in the original collection, your best approach is going to be iterating all the documents to calculate and save the new score.  If you wanted to save to a different collection you could use a [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) instead.

If you are open to other ideas on how to calculate popularity, there are more options :).

#### Improving efficiency

To improve efficiency for your current approach you could:

- Limit your update criteria to documents that have more than 0 votes (otherwise you'll get divide by zero anyway)
- Only retrieve the fields you need to calculate popularity, and update the popularity field with a [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/) rather than re-saving the full document.
- Update the popularity score when you add an individual vote (avoiding a full recalc of all scores every hour) and then do a less frequent (eg. nightly) recalc of all votes

#### Alternative approaches

- Use a popularity metric that can be determined by sorting rather than a calculation.  For example: `{ votes: -1, lastVotedTime: -1, submitTime: -1 }`.  This may not meet your requirements for ageing out the popularity for old documents, though.
- Use a numeric popularity metric where events and user actions (eg. article published, user views/votes/, .. ) will add different values of popularity.  Over time the popularity decays.  The [Radioactivity module for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/radioactivity) implements this with a rules-based approach.

To implement the latter approach in MongoDB, you could:

- Add an integer `popularity` field, where new objects start at a certain value (eg 1000)
- Have different user actions (new voting, views, etc) increase the popularity counter using [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/inc/) by appropriate amounts (for example 50 for a new vote)
- Use a regularly scheduled job to decrement popularity over time.
- Since all popularity starts with a positive score and decays to 0 or less, you can limit your update query to documents with >0 popularity.
- Your could also (ab)use the popularity score to ensure important documents stay popular longer.

There are more nuances to "what is a good popularity metric", and plenty of previous questions on StackOverflow (eg: [What formula should be used to determine “hot” questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)).

Comment: Can I send code to mongodb to run the code in all objects, or do I have to fetch each one, update them and send them back to mongodb?

Comment: Given the type of calculation you are doing you will have to fetch the  objects with relevant fields and update the popularity score with `$set`.  If you want to run the evaluation on the MongoDB server you can use MapReduce, however that will output to a different collection (or an inline result) which may not be what you are after.  Presumably you want the popularity score to end up in the original document so you can use this is search queries?  I suggested some alternative approaches which could be effective in simplifying the calculation.